# Name the effect where text is on a shadow box over an image

Tags: website-design, images, effects, website-templates, drop-shadow

Some examples with text over a transparent background:

See the transparent black background

[image: transparent text box background]

See the text on the shade of cyan

[image: text over cyan background]

What would you call this type of effect?

Comment: Some people might answer that if the purpose of the question would be made clear. Maybe.

Comment: Both of these are different.  The top one is just a transparent text box.  I don't know what the other is supposed to be, but it's truly horrible.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this has a name (may well be proven wrong!) but i would call it a:

"Transparent text box"

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if they have name. The effect is different in the example sites you have given. In the first one, it almost appears as a lightbox effect with text instead of an image. I am referring to the box that has this text: "Pietro Mellini..." You could call that a "transparent overlay box".

But wait a while and someone will provide with more accurate answer.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help guys. Sorry my question...was bad. Thanks for that feedback on that too